# multiple Rollback in spring+hibernate on all if exception occurs on Any

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am performing three crud operation on three different table one after another in same class. If exception occurs on any of it. how can i rollback other crud executed before it in spring+hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Transactional annotation on your method and specify transaction manager.

From Spring Documentation:
http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

And in your code:

```
 @Transactional
 public void updateThreeTables() {
    // Update
    // Update
    // This error will rollback all three
 }
```